# Implementing Material Design onboarding example

Tags: android, android-viewpager, tabbar, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnav

I'm looking at [Material's onboarding design guideline](https://material.io/design/communication/onboarding.html#usage). I was wondering how I should approach replicating this kind of navigation. It seems to incorporate a special bottom tabbar and viewpager. Without the swipe-through feature of viewpager, and with only two buttons skewed to the sides of the bottom tabbar.

[image]